# Insert row from table in another database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE into a table on the current database from a table on another database?

The remote table has 3 additional columns which will need to be ignored (so can't do SELECT *).

Also, is it possible to do multiple rows in one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the operation between two MySQL databases on the same server, it is easy.  See this thread:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,3063,4004#msg-4004

If you want to transfer the data from a database on a different server, or if it is a different kind of database, it is more difficult and you'll probably have to use software or build some.  MySQL doesn't have the database link feature that Oracle has.

-Jon

Comment: SQL Server also has linking capability.